# `importlib` not utilising/recognising path

Tags: python, path, python-module, python-importlib

I am trying to import modules while running my main python script, using a smaller `setup.py` script. However the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) command: `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(name, location)` doesn't appear to be detecting my small python script. Presumably I'm not filling in the `name` or `location` fields correctly.

**Example Script A** (`setup.py`):

```
import os
import pandas as pd

print("success!") # So I can see it has run.
```

**Example Script B** (`my_script.py`):

```
import importlib

setup_path = ("/home/solebay/My Project Name/")
start_up_script = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("setup.py", setup_path)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(start_up_script)
```

Running the above snippet returns:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'
```

I subsequently investigated by running `type(start_up_script)` the result it gives is `typeNone`.

The paths are correct. I verified this by running the following:

```
"/home/solebay/My Project Name/"
sudo python3 "/home/solebay/My Project Name/setup.py"
```

These printed the messages `is a directory` and `success!` respectively.

---

**Note:** *[Maurice Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7216865/maurice-meyer) succeeded in answering my main question, and so I have marked it as correct. However, I have not achieved my main goal; namely importing modules via another script. So if that is your aim, this question might not be appropriate for you.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `location` argument passed to `spec_from_file_location` has to be the full path to the python script:

```
import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(
    name='something__else',  # name is not related to the file, it's the module name!
    location='/tmp/solebay/My Project Name/setup.py'  # full path to the script
)
my_mod = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(my_mod)
print(my_mod)
```

Out:

```
success!
<module 'something__else' from '/tmp/solebay/My Project Name/setup.py'>
```